# How to check for an attribute existing in two tables or subquery results

Tags: mysql, sql

A DVD company has many stores and many different types of DVDs.

`DVD` Table:

```
DVD_NAME         | DVD_CODE
"The Matrix"      | 123
"The Shining"     | 888
"A Scanner Darkly"| 456
```

`Store` Table:

```
LOCATION        | STORE_CODE 
"Buenos Aires"  | "BA"
"Caracas"       | "CA"
"Bogota"        | "BO"
```

`Catalogue` Table:

```
DVD_CODE    | STORE_CODE   | QUANTITY  
123         | "BO"         | 4
888         | "BA"         | 2
123         | "CA"         | 1
456         | "BA"         | 2
123         | "BA"         | 2
888         | "BO"         | 5
```

How would I run a query

I have tried variations of the below code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DVD_CODE, DVD_NAME 
FROM DVD
JOIN CATALOGUE USING (DVD_CODE)
JOIN STORE ON USING (STORE_CODE)
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT DVD_CODE FROM STORE WHERE LOCATION = "Bogota")
   AND EXISTS (SELECT DVD_CODE FROM STORE WHERE LOCATION = "Buenos Aires"));
```

What is being returned is are DVDs that are in either of these stores, but I am wanting to return DVDs that are on hand in both stores, if that makes sense.

This is a simplified version of the problem that I am trying to solve. Any help would be much appreciated. Please excuse any formatting errors and if there's similar answers out there, I'm a newb to both SQL and stack overflow.

Gracias!

Comment: what is your expected output - provide a sample table of your output

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

If you want DVDs in both stores, you can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select c.dvd_code
from catalogue c join
     store s
     on c.store_code = s.store_code
where s.location in ('Bogota', 'Buenos Aires')
group by c.dvd_code
having count(distinct c.store_code) = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   Select dvd_code, count(distinct s.location)
   From catalogue c 
   Left join store s on c.store_code=s.store_code
   group by dvd_code
   having count(distinct s.location)>=2
```